# sysconfig.get_config_var("VERSION") out of date

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just wondering why `sysconfig.get_config_var("VERSION")` is not updated accordingly?

Here's a snippet running in python 3.8.

```py
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> sysconfig.get_config_var("VERSION")
'3.7' # Produces old python version
>>> sysconfig.get_python_version()
'3.8'
```

Thanks!